# How do I generate a random password in a user's language?

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization

My application needs to be I18N compliant. One of the requirements is that the initial password I generate should be in the User's chosen language. What API in Java can I use to achieve this? I have the user's language and will need to get a few random characters from the unicode set of that language.

Edit: Thank you for the answers so far. Some clarifications: This is for a web-based application. For security reasons, we cannot maintain a stock of characters/words in different languages.

Edit 2: In response to the comments and some answers: This application will be deployed in various geographies & I don't want them to have to do work to setup passwords in whichever language they deploy in. That and security are the reasons I've not accepted the most popular answer yet.

Comment: Random passwords are dangerous beasts. In English, for instance, you might want to omit vowels in order to avoid requiring little old grannies to type in obscenities. This doesn't generalise to all languages, however.

Comment: How many languages are you dealing with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I'm not sure setting a default password is a desirable action (people often don't know how to change it and then forget it) if I were doing this, I would get a load of wordlists in various languages and pick perhaps two random words, concatenate and use that as the password.

Means you'll have to do some leg work to find the wordlists but it should be a fairly simple process once you've got them.

Edit: If you're just making random strings, it gets a lot simpler: you just store a file of available characters for each language. Open the right one when you come to generate and then pick random letters. Bish bash bosh. Done.

Edit 2: As Marcelo correctly commented, you could run into the problem of generating some obscene password for the user. It might be worth also keeping localised blacklisted strings to check your password for. If any of the strings appear in the password (just in it, not the whole thing), generate a different password. This does mean you'll never generate an innocent enough password like `scunthorpe` but it also means you won't get things like `assclown` slipping through either.

As you may have gathered, this is starting to look like a lot of work:

- Get all the valid characters for every language you plan to support
- Get all the obscene words for every language you plan to support
- Generate a password based on the letters
- Check none of them contain a swear word
- Remember that some obscene words are adopted by other languages but might not feature on language-specific blacklists so keep an international black-list too.

You might find that setting a pass-*phrase* using known clean words from each language (per my original answer) works better.

If all that looks too stressful, you might be better off re-adjudicating the reason for setting a random password in the first place. If it's an email-verification device, there are other, easier methods to use. Eg: sending a unique link to be clicked

---

**Edit:** Would numbers be okay? They're a ***lot*** safer, don't need combing, are international and can be long enough to be unique, they're just rarely memorable. If they're one-off copy-and-paste jobs, they should do you fine.

If you need them to be short but highly unique (and need lots) perhaps mixing numbers with letters in predictable patterns like (`a` = letter, `n` = number) `annn-annn` gives 676,000,000 combinations. Even simple things like `annn` give enough to not be guessed (26000 combos) if they don't need to be unique... If these *are* passwords, there's nothing wrong with two being the same.

Comment: You've read http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx, haven't you?

Comment: I have now. Had Brian and Barry followed my advise, words like `fukushita` and `kakashite` would have been screened... And it wouldn't take long to generate a phonetic-synonym list to screen out `fukusuka`. Don't get me wrong. Random strings suck because you have to coddle them so much... If you need a random string but you can't be arsed combing over the text, **just use numbers**.

Comment: "fukusuka". Nice one. Perfectly offensive for bilingual english/russian speakers. "need a random string but you can't be arsed combing over the text, just use numbers" I'm pretty sure you can write obscenities using leetspeak with numbers only.

Comment: But you wouldn't usually attempt to pronounce a long string of numbers as a single word. I think you have to look a lot harder to find evil.

Answer (score 4):

The JDK includes the display country names, display language and display text for each locale, stored in all available locales. You could use this to build an initial character set for each locale, and use `Character.toUpperCase` `Character.toLowerCase` to also get case variants.

```
   String getCharsForLocale(Locale locale) {
      Locale[] allLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
      for (Locale l: allLocales) {
          buf.append(l.getDisplayName(locale).toLowerCase())
             .append(l.getDisplayName(locale).toUpperCase())
             .append(l.getDisplaycountry(locale).toLowerCase())
             .append(l.getDisplayCountry(locale).toUpperCase())
             .append(l.getDisplayLanguage(locale).toLowerCase())
             .append(l.getDisplayLanguage(locale).toUpperCase());
      }
      // add other chars, such as decimals
      DecimalFormatSymbols decimals = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
      buf.append(decimals.getMinusSign())
         .append(decimals.getPercent())
         .append(decimals.getDecimalSeparator());
      // etc..

      // now remove dupicates
      char[] chars = new char[buf.length()];
      buf.getChars(0, chars.length, chars, 0);
      Arrays.sort(chars);
      buf = new StringBuilder();
      char last = '\0';
      for (char c: chars) {
          if (c!=last) buf.append(c);
          last = c;
      }
      return buf.toString();
   }
```

While this doesn't exhaustively list every single possible character, the intent is that it lists those that are commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have meaningful words in every language you could use a set of words in english translated (via google translator for example).

Then you can wrap them around with numbers and special characters for password strength.

And of course, in your place, I would instruct the user to immediately change any initial password you provide  to something of his choice.

Comment: +1. While an online translator may not be perfect, this solution definitely lets you stay away from Brian/Barry's curse generator. If you're worried about someone discovering your list of English words (and honestly, if they can access that list, I'd be more worried about the other things they can accomplish than discovering default passwords), you could additionally randomly convert letters in the word to numbers or symbols. 'a' _might_ get converted to '@', or to '4', or not be converted at all.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this sounds a bit tricky. But you can keep a lot of words in a database. And translate them with some translation tool to the user's language. (Maybe [Google](http://translate.google.com/#), but I don't know if Google permits that)
A bit like [reCHAPTA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) does. They have a lot of tekst (like [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/)) where they pick out two words.

You can combine two or three words (with a maximum length) with a number.
Maybe with a their country symbol in front. So you get things like:

- `BE_VogelHuis9751`
- `FR_ChienVoiture3104`
- `ES_GatoEdificio9554`
- `D_BrustTausend9672`
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Unicode Character Database and Unicode Common Locale Data Repository contains a lot of information about languages and scripts. You can access the information using, for instance, [IBM ICU](http://icu-project.org) (a I18N/L10N library more complete than the locales of Java).

In particular, you can get a set of exemplar characters, using [LocaleData.getExemplarSet](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html). Note however that the CLDR is far for complete, you should expect missing data.

Comment: Note that my answer doesn't lessen in any way the relevance of the comment of Marcelo...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx where something similar is described. the key words to look for seem to be "markov chains".

**Edit:** just noticed that dan04 already mentioned that link.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a Latin dictionary with picking random words in CammelCase until
   they are of the desired length.
2. If you insist in getting Unicode fancy, try the [UN UDHR](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/UDHR/Pages/SearchByLang.aspx). Just
   scrape it with some simple regex. Due to the smaller dictionary size
   you might need longer passwords, but who cares.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really interesting question that got me into thinking, and I dipped my hands in the dirt.
Here is my thought process

1. Get the locale (generally standard for language sharing, optional if you have language already)
2. Get language from locale
3. Get Script for the language
4. Get characters (unicode characters) for the script
5. Generate random password.
6. Optionally, time-wrap the process

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/mohitkanwar/7f374c7062994a4a6cc9)

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class LocaleSpecificPasswordGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. get locale : en_US/ es_US/ hi_IN / ud_PK
        // 2. get language from locale
        // 3. get script for language
        // 4. get charset
        // 5. get script characters from charset
        // 6. generate random password
        // 7. time wrap the password generation process
        Locale lo = Locale.ENGLISH;
        int passwordLength = 10;
        String password = timeWrappedPasswordGeneration(lo, passwordLength);
        System.out.println(password);
    }

    private static String timeWrappedPasswordGeneration(Locale lo,
            int passwordLength) {
        long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String password = null;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - curr < 50) {
            password = generateRandomPassword(
                    getCharListForScript(getScriptFromLanguage(lo.getLanguage())),
                    passwordLength);
        }
        return password;
    }

    private static String getScriptFromLanguage(String languageCode) {
        String script = "";
        switch (languageCode) {
        case "ar":
            script = "Arabic";
            break;
        case "as":
            script = "Bengali and Assamese";
            break;
        case "be":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "bg":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "bn":
            script = "Bengali and Assamese";
            break;
        case "ca":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "cs":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "da":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "de":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "el":
            script = "Greek";
            break;
        case "en":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "es":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "et":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "fi":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "fr":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "ga":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "gu":
            script = "Gujarati";
            break;
        case "he":
            script = "Samaritan";
            break;
        case "hi":
            script = "Devanagari";
            break;
        case "hr":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "hu":
            script = "Old Hungarian";
            break;
        case "hy":
            script = "Armenian";
            break;
        case "in":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "is":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "it":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "iw":
            script = "Hebrew";
            break;
        case "ja":
            script = "Katakana";
            break;
        case "ka":
            script = "Georgian";
            break;
        case "kn":
            script = "Kannada";
            break;
        case "ko":
            script = "Hangul Jamo";
            break;
        case "lt":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "lv":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "mk":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "ml":
            script = "Malayalam";
            break;
        case "mn":
            script = "Mongolian";
            break;
        case "ms":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "mt":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "ne":
            script = "Limbu";
            break;
        case "nl":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "no":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "or":
            script = "Oriya";
            break;
        case "pa":
            script = "Gurmukhi";
            break;
        case "pa-IN":
            script = "Gurmukhi";
            break;
        case "pl":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "pt":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "ro":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "ru":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "sk":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "sl":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "sq":
            script = "Caucasian Albanian";
            break;
        case "sr":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "sv":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "ta":
            script = "Tamil";
            break;
        case "te":
            script = "Telugu";
            break;
        case "th":
            script = "Thai";
            break;
        case "tr":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "uk":
            script = "Cyrillic";
            break;
        case "vi":
            script = "Latin";
            break;
        case "zh":
            script = "CJK Unified Ideographs (Han)";
            break;
        default:
            script = "Latin";
        }
        return script;
    }

    private static String generateRandomPassword(List<Character> charlist,
            int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (charlist.size() > 0) {
            while (sb.length() < length) {
                SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
                int charAt = random.nextInt(charlist.size());

                sb.append(charlist.get(charAt));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static List<Character> getCharListForScript(String script) {
        Map<String, Character> initialMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
        Map<String, Character> finalMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
        initialMap.put("Armenian", '\u0530');
        finalMap.put("Armenian", '\u058F');
        initialMap.put("Armenian Ligatures", '\uFB13');
        finalMap.put("Armenian Ligatures", '\uFB17');
        // initialMap.put("Caucasian Albanian",'\u10530');
        // finalMap.put("Caucasian Albanian",'\u1056F');
        // initialMap.put("Cypriot Syllabary",'\u10800');
        // finalMap.put("Cypriot Syllabary",'\u1083F');
        initialMap.put("Cyrillic", '\u0400');
        finalMap.put("Cyrillic", '\u04FF');
        initialMap.put("Cyrillic Supplement", '\u0500');
        finalMap.put("Cyrillic Supplement", '\u052F');
        initialMap.put("Cyrillic Extended-A", '\u2DE0');
        finalMap.put("Cyrillic Extended-A", '\u2DFF');
        initialMap.put("Cyrillic Extended-B", '\uA640');
        finalMap.put("Cyrillic Extended-B", '\uA69F');
        // initialMap.put("Elbasan",'\u10500');
        // finalMap.put("Elbasan",'\u1052F');
        initialMap.put("Georgian", '\u10A0');
        finalMap.put("Georgian", '\u10FF');
        initialMap.put("Georgian Supplement", '\u2D00');
        finalMap.put("Georgian Supplement", '\u2D2F');
        initialMap.put("Glagolitic", '\u2C00');
        finalMap.put("Glagolitic", '\u2C5F');
        // initialMap.put("Gothic",'\u10330');
        // finalMap.put("Gothic",'\u1034F');
        initialMap.put("Greek", '\u0370');
        finalMap.put("Greek", '\u03FF');
        initialMap.put("Greek Extended", '\u1F00');
        finalMap.put("Greek Extended", '\u1FFF');
        // initialMap.put("Ancient Greek Numbers",'\u10140');
        // finalMap.put("Ancient Greek Numbers",'\u1018F');
        initialMap.put("Latin", '\u0020');
        finalMap.put("Latin", '\u007E');
        initialMap.put("Basic Latin (ASCII)", '\u0000');
        finalMap.put("Basic Latin (ASCII)", '\u007F');
        initialMap.put("Latin-1 Supplement", '\u0080');
        finalMap.put("Latin-1 Supplement", '\u00FF');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended-A", '\u0100');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended-A", '\u017F');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended-B", '\u0180');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended-B", '\u024F');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended-C", '\u2C60');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended-C", '\u2C7F');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended-D", '\uA720');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended-D", '\uA7FF');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended-E", '\uAB30');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended-E", '\uAB6F');
        initialMap.put("Latin Extended Additional", '\u1E00');
        finalMap.put("Latin Extended Additional", '\u1EFF');
        initialMap.put("Latin Ligatures", '\uFB00');
        finalMap.put("Latin Ligatures", '\uFB06');
        initialMap.put("Fullwidth Latin Letters", '\uFF00');
        finalMap.put("Fullwidth Latin Letters", '\uFF5E');
        initialMap.put("IPA Extensions", '\u0250');
        finalMap.put("IPA Extensions", '\u02AF');
        initialMap.put("Phonetic Extensions", '\u1D00');
        finalMap.put("Phonetic Extensions", '\u1D7F');
        initialMap.put("Phonetic Extensions Supplement", '\u1D80');
        finalMap.put("Phonetic Extensions Supplement", '\u1DBF');
        // initialMap.put("Linear A",'\u10600');
        // finalMap.put("Linear A",'\u1077F');
        // initialMap.put("Linear B Syllabary",'\u10000');
        // finalMap.put("Linear B Syllabary",'\u1007F');
        // initialMap.put("Linear B Ideograms",'\u10080');
        // finalMap.put("Linear B Ideograms",'\u100FF');
        // initialMap.put("Aegean Numbers",'\u10100');
        // finalMap.put("Aegean Numbers",'\u1013F');
        initialMap.put("Ogham", '\u1680');
        finalMap.put("Ogham", '\u169F');
        // initialMap.put("Old Hungarian",'\u10C80');
        // finalMap.put("Old Hungarian",'\u10CFF');
        // initialMap.put("Old Italic",'\u10300');
        // finalMap.put("Old Italic",'\u1032F');
        // initialMap.put("Old Permic",'\u10350');
        // finalMap.put("Old Permic",'\u1037F');
        // initialMap.put("Phaistos Disc",'\u101D0');
        // finalMap.put("Phaistos Disc",'\u101FF');
        initialMap.put("Runic", '\u16A0');
        finalMap.put("Runic", '\u16FF');
        // initialMap.put("Shavian",'\u10450');
        // finalMap.put("Shavian",'\u1047F');
        initialMap.put("Modifier Tone Letters", '\uA700');
        finalMap.put("Modifier Tone Letters", '\uA71F');
        initialMap.put("Spacing Modifier Letters", '\u02B0');
        finalMap.put("Spacing Modifier Letters", '\u02FF');
        initialMap.put("Superscripts and Subscripts", '\u2070');
        finalMap.put("Superscripts and Subscripts", '\u209F');
        initialMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks", '\u0300');
        finalMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks", '\u036F');
        initialMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks Extended", '\u1AB0');
        finalMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks Extended", '\u1AFF');
        initialMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement", '\u1DC0');
        finalMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement", '\u1DFF');
        initialMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols", '\u20D0');
        finalMap.put("Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols", '\u20FF');
        initialMap.put("Combining Half Marks", '\uFE20');
        finalMap.put("Combining Half Marks", '\uFE2F');
        initialMap.put("Bamum", '\uA6A0');
        finalMap.put("Bamum", '\uA6FF');
        // initialMap.put("Bamum Supplement",'\u16800');
        // finalMap.put("Bamum Supplement",'\u16A3F');
        // initialMap.put("Bassa Vah",'\u16AD0');
        // finalMap.put("Bassa Vah",'\u16AFF');
        initialMap.put("Coptic", '\u2C80');
        finalMap.put("Coptic", '\u2CFF');
        initialMap.put("Coptic in Greek block", '\u03E2');
        finalMap.put("Coptic in Greek block", '\u03EF');
        // initialMap.put("Coptic Epact Numbers",'\u102E0');
        // finalMap.put("Coptic Epact Numbers",'\u102FF');
        // initialMap.put("Egyptian Hieroglyphs",'\u13000');
        // finalMap.put("Egyptian Hieroglyphs",'\u1342F');
        initialMap.put("Ethiopic", '\u1200');
        finalMap.put("Ethiopic", '\u137F');
        initialMap.put("Ethiopic Supplement", '\u1380');
        finalMap.put("Ethiopic Supplement", '\u139F');
        initialMap.put("Ethiopic Extended", '\u2D80');
        finalMap.put("Ethiopic Extended", '\u2DDF');
        initialMap.put("Ethiopic Extended-A", '\uAB00');
        finalMap.put("Ethiopic Extended-A", '\uAB2F');
        // initialMap.put("Mende Kikakui",'\u1E800');
        // finalMap.put("Mende Kikakui",'\u1E8DF');
        // initialMap.put("Meroitic Cursive",'\u109A0');
        // finalMap.put("Meroitic Cursive",'\u109FF');
        // initialMap.put("Meroitic Hieroglyphs",'\u10980');
        // finalMap.put("Meroitic Hieroglyphs",'\u1099F');
        initialMap.put("N&#39;Ko", '\u07C0');
        finalMap.put("N&#39;Ko", '\u07FF');
        // initialMap.put("Osmanya",'\u10480');
        // finalMap.put("Osmanya",'\u104AF');
        initialMap.put("Tifinagh", '\u2D30');
        finalMap.put("Tifinagh", '\u2D7F');
        initialMap.put("Vai", '\uA500');
        finalMap.put("Vai", '\uA63F');
        // initialMap.put("Anatolian Hieroglyphs",'\u14400');
        // finalMap.put("Anatolian Hieroglyphs",'\u1467F');
        initialMap.put("Arabic", '\u0600');
        finalMap.put("Arabic", '\u06FF');
        initialMap.put("Arabic Supplement", '\u0750');
        finalMap.put("Arabic Supplement", '\u077F');
        initialMap.put("Arabic Extended-A", '\u08A0');
        finalMap.put("Arabic Extended-A", '\u08FF');
        initialMap.put("Arabic Presentation Forms-A", '\uFB50');
        finalMap.put("Arabic Presentation Forms-A", '\uFDFF');
        initialMap.put("Arabic Presentation Forms-B", '\uFE70');
        finalMap.put("Arabic Presentation Forms-B", '\uFEFF');
        // initialMap.put("Aramaic, Imperial",'\u10840');
        // finalMap.put("Aramaic, Imperial",'\u1085F');
        // initialMap.put("Avestan",'\u10B00');
        // finalMap.put("Avestan",'\u10B3F');
        // initialMap.put("Carian",'\u102A0');
        // finalMap.put("Carian",'\u102DF');
        // initialMap.put("Cuneiform",'\u12000');
        // finalMap.put("Cuneiform",'\u123FF');
        // initialMap.put("Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation",'\u12400');
        // finalMap.put("Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation",'\u1247F');
        // initialMap.put("Early Dynastic Cuneiform",'\u12480');
        // finalMap.put("Early Dynastic Cuneiform",'\u1254F');
        // initialMap.put("Old Persian",'\u103A0');
        // finalMap.put("Old Persian",'\u103DF');
        // initialMap.put("Ugaritic",'\u10380');
        // finalMap.put("Ugaritic",'\u1039F');
        // initialMap.put("Hatran",'\u108E0');
        // finalMap.put("Hatran",'\u108FF');
        initialMap.put("Hebrew", '\u0590');
        finalMap.put("Hebrew", '\u05FF');
        initialMap.put("Hebrew Presentation Forms", '\uFB1D');
        finalMap.put("Hebrew Presentation Forms", '\uFB4F');
        // initialMap.put("Lycian",'\u10280');
        // finalMap.put("Lycian",'\u1029F');
        // initialMap.put("Lydian",'\u10920');
        // finalMap.put("Lydian",'\u1093F');
        initialMap.put("Mandaic", '\u0840');
        finalMap.put("Mandaic", '\u085F');
        // initialMap.put("Nabataean",'\u10880');
        // finalMap.put("Nabataean",'\u108AF');
        // initialMap.put("Old North Arabian",'\u10A80');
        // finalMap.put("Old North Arabian",'\u10A9F');
        // initialMap.put("Old South Arabian",'\u10A60');
        // finalMap.put("Old South Arabian",'\u10A7F');
        // initialMap.put("Pahlavi, Inscriptional",'\u10B60');
        // finalMap.put("Pahlavi, Inscriptional",'\u10B7F');
        // initialMap.put("Pahlavi, Psalter",'\u10B80');
        // finalMap.put("Pahlavi, Psalter",'\u10BAF');
        // initialMap.put("Palmyrene",'\u10860');
        // finalMap.put("Palmyrene",'\u1087F');
        // initialMap.put("Parthian, Inscriptional",'\u10B40');
        // finalMap.put("Parthian, Inscriptional",'\u10B5F');
        // initialMap.put("Phoenician",'\u10900');
        // finalMap.put("Phoenician",'\u1091F');
        initialMap.put("Samaritan", '\u0800');
        finalMap.put("Samaritan", '\u083F');
        initialMap.put("Syriac", '\u0700');
        finalMap.put("Syriac", '\u074F');
        // initialMap.put("Manichaean",'\u10AC0');
        // finalMap.put("Manichaean",'\u10AFF');
        initialMap.put("Mongolian", '\u1800');
        finalMap.put("Mongolian", '\u18AF');
        // initialMap.put("Old Turkic",'\u10C00');
        // finalMap.put("Old Turkic",'\u10C4F');
        // initialMap.put("Phags-Pa",'\u10C00');
        // finalMap.put("Phags-Pa",'\u10C4F');
        initialMap.put("Tibetan", '\u0F00');
        finalMap.put("Tibetan", '\u0FFF');
        // initialMap.put("Ahom",'\u11700');
        // finalMap.put("Ahom",'\u1173F');
        initialMap.put("Bengali and Assamese", '\u0980');
        finalMap.put("Bengali and Assamese", '\u09FF');
        // initialMap.put("Brahmi",'\u11000');
        // finalMap.put("Brahmi",'\u1107F');
        // initialMap.put("Chakma",'\u11100');
        // finalMap.put("Chakma",'\u1114F');
        initialMap.put("Devanagari", '\u0900');
        finalMap.put("Devanagari", '\u097F');
        initialMap.put("Devanagari Extended", '\uA8E0');
        finalMap.put("Devanagari Extended", '\uA8FF');
        // initialMap.put("Grantha",'\u11300');
        // finalMap.put("Grantha",'\u1137F');
        initialMap.put("Gujarati", '\u0A80');
        finalMap.put("Gujarati", '\u0AFF');
        initialMap.put("Gurmukhi", '\u0A05');
        finalMap.put("Gurmukhi", '\u0A71');
        // initialMap.put("Kaithi",'\u11080');
        // finalMap.put("Kaithi",'\u110CF');
        initialMap.put("Kannada", '\u0C80');
        finalMap.put("Kannada", '\u0CFF');
        // initialMap.put("Kharoshthi",'\u10A00');
        // finalMap.put("Kharoshthi",'\u10A5F');
        // initialMap.put("Khojki",'\u11200');
        // finalMap.put("Khojki",'\u1124F');
        // initialMap.put("Khudawadi",'\u112B0');
        // finalMap.put("Khudawadi",'\u112FF');
        initialMap.put("Lepcha", '\u1C00');
        finalMap.put("Lepcha", '\u1C4F');
        initialMap.put("Limbu", '\u1900');
        finalMap.put("Limbu", '\u194F');
        // initialMap.put("Mahajani",'\u11150');
        // finalMap.put("Mahajani",'\u1117F');
        initialMap.put("Malayalam", '\u0D00');
        finalMap.put("Malayalam", '\u0D7F');
        initialMap.put("Meetei Mayek", '\uABC0');
        finalMap.put("Meetei Mayek", '\uABFF');
        initialMap.put("Meetei Mayek Extensions", '\uAAE0');
        finalMap.put("Meetei Mayek Extensions", '\uAAFF');
        // initialMap.put("Modi",'\u11600');
        // finalMap.put("Modi",'\u1165F');
        // initialMap.put("Mro",'\u16A40');
        // finalMap.put("Mro",'\u16A6F');
        // initialMap.put("Multani",'\u11280');
        // finalMap.put("Multani",'\u112AF');
        initialMap.put("Ol Chiki", '\u1C50');
        finalMap.put("Ol Chiki", '\u1C7F');
        initialMap.put("Oriya (Odia)", '\u0B00');
        finalMap.put("Oriya (Odia)", '\u0B7F');
        initialMap.put("Saurashtra", '\uA880');
        finalMap.put("Saurashtra", '\uA8DF');
        // initialMap.put("Sharada",'\u11180');
        // finalMap.put("Sharada",'\u111DF');
        // initialMap.put("Siddham",'\u11580');
        // finalMap.put("Siddham",'\u115FF');
        initialMap.put("Sinhala", '\u0D80');
        finalMap.put("Sinhala", '\u0DFF');
        // initialMap.put("Sinhala Archaic Numbers",'\u111E0');
        // finalMap.put("Sinhala Archaic Numbers",'\u111FF');
        // initialMap.put("Sora Sompeng",'\u110D0');
        // finalMap.put("Sora Sompeng",'\u110FF');
        initialMap.put("Syloti Nagri", '\uA800');
        finalMap.put("Syloti Nagri", '\uA82F');
        // initialMap.put("Takri",'\u11680');
        // finalMap.put("Takri",'\u116CF');
        initialMap.put("Tamil", '\u0B80');
        finalMap.put("Tamil", '\u0BFF');
        initialMap.put("Telugu", '\u0C00');
        finalMap.put("Telugu", '\u0C7F');
        initialMap.put("Thaana", '\u0780');
        finalMap.put("Thaana", '\u07BF');
        // initialMap.put("Tirhuta",'\u11480');
        // finalMap.put("Tirhuta",'\u114DF');
        initialMap.put("Vedic Extensions", '\u1CD0');
        finalMap.put("Vedic Extensions", '\u1CFF');
        // initialMap.put("Warang Citi",'\u118A0');
        // finalMap.put("Warang Citi",'\u118FF');
        initialMap.put("Cham", '\uAA00');
        finalMap.put("Cham", '\uAA5F');
        initialMap.put("Kayah Li", '\uA900');
        finalMap.put("Kayah Li", '\uA92F');
        initialMap.put("Khmer", '\u1780');
        finalMap.put("Khmer", '\u17FF');
        initialMap.put("Khmer Symbols", '\u19E0');
        finalMap.put("Khmer Symbols", '\u19FF');
        initialMap.put("Lao", '\u0E80');
        finalMap.put("Lao", '\u0EFF');
        initialMap.put("Myanmar", '\u1000');
        finalMap.put("Myanmar", '\u109F');
        initialMap.put("Myanmar Extended-A", '\uAA60');
        finalMap.put("Myanmar Extended-A", '\uAA7F');
        initialMap.put("Myanmar Extended-B", '\uA9E0');
        finalMap.put("Myanmar Extended-B", '\uA9FF');
        initialMap.put("New Tai Lue", '\u1980');
        finalMap.put("New Tai Lue", '\u19DF');
        // initialMap.put("Pahawh Hmong",'\u16B00');
        // finalMap.put("Pahawh Hmong",'\u16B8F');
        // initialMap.put("Pau Cin Hau",'\u11AC0');
        // finalMap.put("Pau Cin Hau",'\u11AFF');
        initialMap.put("Tai Le", '\u1950');
        finalMap.put("Tai Le", '\u197F');
        initialMap.put("Tai Tham", '\u1A20');
        finalMap.put("Tai Tham", '\u1AAF');
        initialMap.put("Tai Viet", '\uAA80');
        finalMap.put("Tai Viet", '\uAADF');
        initialMap.put("Thai", '\u0E00');
        finalMap.put("Thai", '\u0E7F');
        initialMap.put("Balinese", '\u1B00');
        finalMap.put("Balinese", '\u1B7F');
        initialMap.put("Batak", '\u1BC0');
        finalMap.put("Batak", '\u1BFF');
        initialMap.put("Buginese", '\u1A00');
        finalMap.put("Buginese", '\u1A1F');
        initialMap.put("Buhid", '\u1740');
        finalMap.put("Buhid", '\u175F');
        initialMap.put("Hanunoo", '\u1720');
        finalMap.put("Hanunoo", '\u173F');
        initialMap.put("Javanese", '\uA980');
        finalMap.put("Javanese", '\uA9DF');
        initialMap.put("Rejang", '\uA930');
        finalMap.put("Rejang", '\uA95F');
        initialMap.put("Sundanese", '\uA930');
        finalMap.put("Sundanese", '\uA95F');
        initialMap.put("Sundanese Supplement", '\u1CC0');
        finalMap.put("Sundanese Supplement", '\u1CCF');
        initialMap.put("Tagalog", '\u1700');
        finalMap.put("Tagalog", '\u171F');
        initialMap.put("Tagbanwa", '\u1760');
        finalMap.put("Tagbanwa", '\u177F');
        initialMap.put("Bopomofo", '\u3100');
        finalMap.put("Bopomofo", '\u312F');
        initialMap.put("Bopomofo Extended", '\u31A0');
        finalMap.put("Bopomofo Extended", '\u31BF');
        initialMap.put("CJK Unified Ideographs (Han)", '\u4E00');
        finalMap.put("CJK Unified Ideographs (Han)", '\u9FFF');
        initialMap.put("CJK  Extension-A", '\u3400');
        finalMap.put("CJK  Extension-A", '\u4DBF');
        // initialMap.put("CJK Extension B",'\u20000');
        // finalMap.put("CJK Extension B",'\u2A6DF');
        // initialMap.put("CJK Extension C",'\u2A700');
        // finalMap.put("CJK Extension C",'\u2B73F');
        // initialMap.put("CJK Extension D",'\u2B740');
        // finalMap.put("CJK Extension D",'\u2B81F');
        // initialMap.put("CJK Extension E",'\u2B820');
        // finalMap.put("CJK Extension E",'\u2CEAF');
        initialMap.put("CJK Compatibility Ideographs", '\uF900');
        finalMap.put("CJK Compatibility Ideographs", '\uFAFF');
        // initialMap.put("CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement",'\u2F800');
        // finalMap.put("CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement",'\u2FA1F');
        initialMap.put("CJK Radicals / KangXi Radicals", '\u2F00');
        finalMap.put("CJK Radicals / KangXi Radicals", '\u2FDF');
        initialMap.put("CJK Radicals Supplement", '\u2E80');
        finalMap.put("CJK Radicals Supplement", '\u2EFF');
        initialMap.put("CJK Strokes", '\u31C0');
        finalMap.put("CJK Strokes", '\u31EF');
        initialMap.put("Ideographic Description Characters", '\u2FF0');
        finalMap.put("Ideographic Description Characters", '\u2FFF');
        initialMap.put("Hangul Jamo", '\u1100');
        finalMap.put("Hangul Jamo", '\u11FF');
        initialMap.put("Hangul Jamo Extended-A", '\uA960');
        finalMap.put("Hangul Jamo Extended-A", '\uA97F');
        initialMap.put("Hangul Jamo Extended-B", '\uD7B0');
        finalMap.put("Hangul Jamo Extended-B", '\uD7FF');
        initialMap.put("Hangul Compatibility Jamo", '\u3130');
        finalMap.put("Hangul Compatibility Jamo", '\u318F');
        initialMap.put("Halfwidth Jamo", '\uFFA0');
        finalMap.put("Halfwidth Jamo", '\uFFDC');
        initialMap.put("Hangul Syllables", '\uAC00');
        finalMap.put("Hangul Syllables", '\uD7AF');
        initialMap.put("Hiragana", '\u3040');
        finalMap.put("Hiragana", '\u309F');
        initialMap.put("Katakana", '\u30A0');
        finalMap.put("Katakana", '\u30FF');
        initialMap.put("Katakana Phonetic Extensions", '\u31F0');
        finalMap.put("Katakana Phonetic Extensions", '\u31FF');
        // initialMap.put("Kana Supplement",'\u1B000');
        // finalMap.put("Kana Supplement",'\u1B0FF');
        initialMap.put("Halfwidth Katakana", '\uFF65');
        finalMap.put("Halfwidth Katakana", '\uFF9F');
        initialMap.put("Kanbun", '\u3190');
        finalMap.put("Kanbun", '\u319F');
        initialMap.put("Lisu", '\uA4D0');
        finalMap.put("Lisu", '\uA4FF');
        // initialMap.put("Miao",'\u16F00');
        // finalMap.put("Miao",'\u16F9F');
        initialMap.put("Yi Syllables", '\uA000');
        finalMap.put("Yi Syllables", '\uA48F');
        initialMap.put("Yi Radicals", '\uA490');
        finalMap.put("Yi Radicals", '\uA4CF');
        initialMap.put("Cherokee", '\u13A0');
        finalMap.put("Cherokee", '\u13FF');
        initialMap.put("Cherokee Supplement", '\uAB70');
        finalMap.put("Cherokee Supplement", '\uABBF');
        // initialMap.put("Deseret",'\u10400');
        // finalMap.put("Deseret",'\u1044F');
        initialMap.put("Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics", '\u1400');
        finalMap.put("Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics", '\u167F');
        initialMap.put("UCAS Extended", '\u18B0');
        finalMap.put("UCAS Extended", '\u18FF');
        initialMap.put("Alphabetic Presentation Forms", '\uFB00');
        finalMap.put("Alphabetic Presentation Forms", '\uFB4F');
        initialMap.put("ASCII Characters", '\u0000');
        finalMap.put("ASCII Characters", '\u007F');
        initialMap.put("Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms", '\uFF00');
        finalMap.put("Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms", '\uFFEF');

        Character ab = initialMap.get(script.trim());
        Character b = finalMap.get(script.trim());
        List<Character> reqCharList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        if (ab != null) {
            while (!ab.equals(b)) {
                reqCharList.add(ab);
                ab++;
            }
        }
        return reqCharList;
    }
}
```

Known issues with code:

1. It handles simple unicodes (4 characters) only- It can be extended to handle other unicode characters as well, if required
2. As of now, it depends upon range of characters in a script. If few characters are added later, or are out of range the code would not cover them. If some characters in defined range belong to other scripts, they would be misleading. This can be resolved by improving the characters related to a script.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can create an english word, and translate it with google translate it